# How to disable lazy load on mobiles?

Tags: jquery-lazyload

I have installed the Appelsiini Lazy Load and it works fine on desktop view. How can i disable this to mobile. This is the website of the lazy load - www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: What is your definition of mobile device? Is tablets mobile ones? And Surface Pro 2?

Comment: And what is the reason to disable Lazy Load? Blank images when user scrolls?

Comment: @Denis - I mean i am testing on my mobile phone and when lazy load is enabled. None of the images were shown, maybe lazy load is not working on my nokia 5233 but when i disable the lazy load, everything works fine. Mobile device means simple like iPhone, Nokia, Android etc.

Comment: I don't have Symbian 9 device to reproduce the issue (and I don't see such a device on Nokia's rda.cellulardata.com service, but seems it was there previously). BTW, could you confirm that http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt plugin doesn't work as well? And is it may be that javascript is disabled in Symbian's browser and don't have noscript-wrapped images for this case?

Comment: If the issue is specific to Symbian, you can check browser's User-Agent string like `<script type="text/javascript">if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/SymbianOS/i)) document.write('<script src="/path/to/jquery.lazyload.min.js"><\/script>');</script>`, that is to load jquery.lazyload.min.js depending on a condition.

Comment: sorry, above code doesn't work (if jquery.lazyload.min.js is not loaded, images will not be displayed). Try trick with "infinite" threshold option: `$("img.lazy").lazyload(navigator.userAgent.match(/SymbianOS/i) ? {threshold: 1e10} : {});`

Comment: @Denis: I don't know  before that Opera also have one more version, specially for mobiles, and that one is Opera Mobile. I am using Opera Mini and that's why i am unable to see any javascript effects. After installing Opera Mobile, now everything was working fine including Lazy Load, Slider and Menu. However lazy load taking time to show the images but it is ok for my nokia phone.

Comment: This snippet should work in Opera Mini: `$("img.lazy").lazyload(window.operamini ? {threshold: 1e10} : {});` (Lazy Load XT with similar patch works correctly, so I guess Mika Tuupola's Lazy Load plugin should work as well).